# Nforce nodejs salesforce search not working

Tags: node.js, salesforce, soql

I followed nforce [link](https://github.com/kevinohara80/nforce) to search for objects like this

```
var selectQuery = "SELECT Name FROM Account Name = 'Spiffy Cleaners'";
org.query({ query: selectQuery, oauth: oauth}, function(err, resp){
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
unexpected token: =]


errorCode: 'MALFORMED_QUERY',
  body: 
   [ { message: '\nSELECT Name FROM Account Name = \'Spiffy Cleaners\'\n                             ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:30\nunexpected token: =',
       errorCode: 'MALFORMED_QUERY' } ],
  statusCode: 400 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `WHERE` statement:

```
SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Spiffy Cleaners'
```

Comment: Whoops.  Totally missed the lack of a `WHERE` statement.